# python regex pattern finding

Tags: python

I am trying to replace existing value  to

input:

```
a = """{"value”:”123456789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”1234567891234”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”1234567891234567”,”id":"2"}"""
```

expected output:

```
 """{"value”:”aaaaaa789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaa234”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaaaaa567”,”id":"2"}"""
```

=============

```
a = """{"value”:”123456789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”1234567891234”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”1234567891234567”,”id":"2"}"""
b = re.sub('\d{6}','aaaaaa', str(a))
print(b)
{"value”:”aaaaaa789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaaaa4”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaaaa4567”,”id":"2"}
```

================

Any help would be great.

Comment: So are wanting to sort by value? Is you actual data valid json and this is just a typoed version?

Comment: Actual input is a string. From the string i am trying to find a pattern with digits..

Comment: a = """{"value”:”123456789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”1234567891234”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”1234567891234567”,”id":"2"}"""

Comment: b = re.sub('\d{6}','aaaaaa', str(a))

Comment: Please re-write your question as it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.  Pretend we know nothing of your scenario (as we don't), and explain detail by detail.

Comment: _Any help would be great._ Help with what? You haven't outlined a specific problem, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

It substitutes all digits which have trailing three or more digits:

```py
import re

text = """{"value”:”123456789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”1234567891234”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”1234567891234567”,”id":"2"}"""
expected = """{"value”:”aaaaaa789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaa234”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaaaaa567”,”id":"2"}"""
pattern = re.compile(r'\d(?=\d{3})')

result = pattern.sub('a', text)
print(result)
print(result == expected)
```

output:

```py
{"value”:”aaaaaa789”,”id":"0"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaa234”,”id":"1"},{"value”:”aaaaaaaaaaaaa567”,”id":"2"}
True
```

Or without `re.compile`:

```py
result = re.sub(r'\d(?=\d{3})', 'a', text)
```

---

#### Explanation

- `\d` matches digits(equals to `[0-9]`).
- `(?=\d{3})` is "Positive lookahead". It matches in poistion which has following `\d{3}`(three digits).
- So it substitutes any digits which has following three digits, to `'a'`.

Comment: @Onyambu Okay, my mistake. Thanks for advise :)

Comment: Awesome Man. Thanks Choi.

Comment: @parker Happy to help! Please don't forget to accept an answer if it resolves the question. :)